# Qt Creator compilation error

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I'm trying to compile a very simple code in Qt Creator by creating a new "Qt Quick UI Application" but when I have tried to build it & run it, It showed for me a box where the title says "visual studio Just-In-Time Debugger" & inside the box there was an error message that says " An Unhandled win32 exception occurred in qmlscene.ece [6140] " & an option to choose one of the possible debuggers listed ( In my case there is only " New instance of visual studio 2008 " ) & the problem is when i choose that debugger it doesn't work for me & it gives me this message " No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed. "

here is my code :

**1. newProj.qmlproject**

/* File generated by Qt Creator */

```
import QmlProject 1.1

Project {
mainFile: "newProj.qml"

/* Include .qml, .js, and image files from current directory and subdirectories */
QmlFiles {
    directory: "."
}
JavaScriptFiles {
    directory: "."
}
ImageFiles {
    directory: "."
}
/* List of plugin directories passed to QML runtime */
// importPaths: [ "../exampleplugin" ]
}
```

**2. newProj.qml**

```
       import QtQuick 2.0

      Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
      anchors.centerIn: parent
       text: "Hello World"
    }
     MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked: {
        Qt.quit();
       }
     }
     }
```

here is a screenshot of the box appears to me :

[image]

To make the long story short i would like to build my code in Qt Creator itself not in visual studio so how this can be done ?

thx,

Comment: You have not shared your example. As for your second question, you do not have symbols probably because you got stripped builds, i.e. release without debug information.

Comment: Still vague. You shared some qml code, and you also wrote about compilation error, but qml is not compiled.

Comment: but it's weird because that box shouldn't appear anyways even if it's not built

Comment: the output should appears in a qmlscene.exe without the need of visual studio